# Is data in RAM permanently cleared after a reboot?

Tags: windows, paging, ram, reboot

I am being told sensitive data held in RAM is permanently cleared out by rebooting a Windows (10) machine. Is this correct?

RAM is extended by paging data to and from the paging file (C:\pagefile.sys) using various algortihms. My understanding is that after a reboot, any data that has been in RAM could/would still be held in the paging file and potentially reloaded back into RAM (either predictively or referencing a nearby page, etc., whatever algorithm), which means a reboot does not neccessarily clear data permanently from RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Page File**

Windows can be configured to flush the pagefile on system shutdown (kb314834):

Registry Key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management`
REG_DWORD Value: `ClearPageFileAtShutdown` = 1

From Windows Internals Part 1 (7th ed):

> Because the page file contains parts of process and kernel virtual
> memory, for security reasons, the system can be configured to clear
> the page file at system shutdown. To enable this, set the `ClearPageFileAtShutdown` registry value in the
> `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management` key to 1. Otherwise, after shutdown, the page file will
> contain whatever data happened to have been paged out while the system
> was up. This data could then be accessed by someone who gained
> physical access to the machine.

Doing this will certainly make normal system shutdowns and reboots slower. *Also keep in mind that abnormal shutdowns can still leave sensitive data in the pagefile.*

Otherwise, the on-disk contents of the pagefile (or hibernation file) can certainly contain stale data after a reboot.

**RAM**

Technically, RAM can still be physically inspected after shutdown and some data can be retrieved for a short period of time after power loss. This is typically referred to as a [Cold-Boot-Attack](https://blog.f-secure.com/cold-boot-attacks/). Variants on this can extend the time data is available by dropping the temperature of the chips.

https://freedom-to-tinker.com/2008/02/21/new-research-result-cold-boot-attacks-disk-encryption/

> data in DRAM actually fades out gradually over a period of seconds to
> minutes, enabling an attacker to read the full contents of memory by
> cutting power and then rebooting into a malicious operating system.
>
> Interestingly, if you cool the DRAM chips, for example by spraying
> inverted cans of “canned air” dusting spray on them, the chips will
> retain their contents for much longer. At these temperatures (around
> -50 °C) you can remove the chips from the computer and let them sit on the table for ten minutes or more, without appreciable loss of data

[Lest We Remember: Cold Boot Attacks on Encryption Keys](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/sec08/tech/full_papers/halderman/halderman.pdf)

But from a standard reboot, you will likely find it difficult to reference stale data from a memory address without bypassing the Windows memory manager which keeps track of what pages are in-use/dirty. As soon as you try to use a dirty page from RAM windows will zero initialize it.